# Bootstrap 5 Grid System .. More than 12 Columns in a row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am following an online course & in The Bootstrap project they classified one row into more than 12 Columns, so is it possible .. I really got confused!?

[image: The row had planned to have col-lg-6 for 3 times]

Answer (score 1):

There is 12 columns per row on Bootstraps' grid system. In your example, the third column `col-lg-6` will display at the second row(new line) on the large breakpoint, like this below :

```html
1(col-lg-6)      |     2(col-lg-6)
3(col-lg-6)      |
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#row-columns

Comment: Thanks a lot & I had checked the output but my concern aren't we should just make use of 12 columns only! or this is some cases only!

Comment: In sometime, we put multiple posts on a `.row`, each of row have 4 columns, like this `<row><article col-3><article col-3><article col-3><article col-3><article col-3><article col-3><article col-3>...</row>`，all these posts will filling the entiry page.

Comment: You can visit this page https://fastbootstrap.com/components/, view the page source, it put multiple `col-md-6 col-lg-4`  in a `.row`. if two or more items that there total columns over 12-columns, it will auto break new line.